# how can you survive /kill?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So there's a video by Zyph and according to him it is possible but it is 1.8 and you have to have resistance level 5 to survive /kill but can you survive this op command in 1.16?

Answer (score 3):

**No, it is impossible to survive this command** as `/kill` originally dealt 1,000 damage, which used to allow it to be possible to survive with Resistance V, but as *Penguin* said, it just instant kills now.

Answer (score 2):

No, `/kill` literally just kills the player. There are no effects, armor, etc. that can allow you tp pass this.

Comment: Totem of undying?

Comment: Totem of undying has no effect on the /kill command. Commands like these often ignore items like ToD and execute their function unless specifically told otherwise.

Comment: oh, because i remember my totem getting popped when someone tried to /kill me a while back, so this feature was removed just for /kill?